# What are the differences between APIView and Django generic views in terms of usage?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build a Django backend API that will be accessible both by a mobile app and a website. I am setting up the user authentication functionality using the `rest-framework` module.

Can anyone explain the difference in functionality and usage between the two types of views (`APIView` and Django display/editing generic views) and which ones would be more suitable for my goals?

Comment: `rest_framework` views: JSON APIs for JS/Ajax front-end and exposing your data to third parties. `Django` generic views: for serving HTML, files, redirects etc

Comment: Here is the different of the `from rest_framework.views import APIView` this class extends from this `from django.views.generic import View` and some attributes added to it to use in Rest APIs. You can see here [APIView](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.views/APIView.html) and [VIew](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.base/View/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `viewsets.ModelViewSet` when you are going to allow all or most of CRUD operations on a model.

Use `generics.*` when you only want to allow some operations on a model

Use `APIView` when you want to completely customize the behaviour.

baed on https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-api-polls-tutorial/en/latest/more-views-and-viewsets.html